# What language is used in this slide from Google Next

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was watching a Google Next session, as I'm interested in Google's cloud and their Go language.

Developer ecosystems/communities have their ways of doing things, cultural customs, which can be really alien to outsiders who don't have the experience to fill-in the gaps.

So I have a few noob questions:

- What language is this?
- What language does Google use in samples, Python, Go, or pseudo code?

[image: Google session slide with code snippet]

- Why is there a call to `getFailedInserts()` but the result of the get isn't assigned to anything?
- Is it normal to use what I call magic strings, i.e. "WriteMutatedRecords", as instructions instead of naming a method as such or using an enum, or string consts?

Comment: It's Java, and it shows the Apache Beam SDK being used to write the results of the pipeline to BigQuery. You can read more about it here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#applying-transforms: _"invoking multiple Beam transforms is similar to method chaining, but with one slight difference: You apply the transform to the input PCollection, passing the transform itself as an argument, and the operation returns the output PCollection. This takes the general form:"_ The "magic strings" are the labels/names for the step in the Dataflow/Beam pipeline for easier readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example looks like it is written in Scala or Java. You can tell from a number of indicators:

- The code has a Java-style syntax
- Methods are called on objects (e.g. `input`), which means it is an object-oriented language
- `new BigQuerySchemaMutator()` is typical for a Java - style constructor

These indicators do not, however, give any indication wether it is Scala or Java. The syntax of these languages is very similar, and both are JVM - lanugages.

The strongest indicator for Scala in my opinion is that the code is written in a functional matter, and it contains two method invocations on `BigQueryIO`, which could either be a static method for the class `BigQueryIO` itself in case of Java, or is a method defined on the `object BigQueryIO` in Scala, which is a common design pattern in the language.

There is, however, the final `;` which would only be necessary with Java.

For someone reading the code example this question is actually not important, because Apache Beam (which is the SDK that seems to be used here) is a Java library - which can be used both in Java and Scala.

---

The result of `getFailedInserts` seems to be further processed by calling `.apply` on it. This kind of style is called *functional programming*.

It's a whole different approach to programming, instead of the common procedural programming patterns found in most other lanugages. (e.g. storing something in a variable / variables in general)

Note that this example doesn't actually contain any functional programming per se (e.g. higher order functions alias lambdas), but the functional programming style is obvious.

---

It is always considered best practice to not have magic strings, but for such a code example they probably wanted to keep the code as simple as possible - as it is a one-liner already (allthough with line breaks).

Answer (score 2):

The code example is Java using Apache Beam programming model (https://beam.apache.org/)

I believe the complete code from the slide is here:
https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-dynamic-schema/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pso/pipeline/DynamicSchemaPipeline.java

The code from slide:

1. tries to insert data into a table 'events_table'
2. If it returns a transient error from Big Query API (for example "column 'foo' does not exist") it runs a table mutation adding 'foo' and inserts data again.

It is a pattern to create flexible tables into Big Query which is a predefined schema columnar database.